# vue/ts application in webpack shows: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I need to add a Vue widget to an existing TypeScript application. Vue has been advertised as a library that easily allows you to implement a graphical view:

> Vue.js is more flexible, less straightforward in the solution. This allows you to structure your application as you want, rather than forcing it to do everything in Angular. Vue is just a presentation layer, so you can use it as an unobtrusive feature on the application page, instead of a full-scale framework.

But when I searched around about how to implement a component in Vue + TypeScript, the only references that I've found were about the vue-cli, that wouldn't adapt to a pre-existing application where the vue component is just one of many.

I tried to took advantage as much as possible, so I got the vue-ts hello world app and stuck it with a custom webpack configuration. After a lot of tries, this was the most promising `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
require('file-loader');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'main.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              use: 'ts-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            use: [{loader: 'vue-loader', options: {loaders: {}, esModule: false}}, {loader: 'ts-loader'}]
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
              useRelativePath: true
            }
          }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './index.html'}),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js' // I tried all of these...
    },
    extensions: ['.vue', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },
};
```

However, even if the build completes with no effort, the Hello World page doesn't appear and I see this message in the console:

> vue.js:633 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render
>   function not defined.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/App.vue

This is my `package.json`:

```
{ ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vue": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.9",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.4",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```

The folder that I'm trying to compile is composed by 3 files on different levels, typical of *vue-cli* applications: *main.ts*, *App.vue* and *HelloWorld.vue*. I don't post the code to keep the question as clear as possible, but if it's needed just ask it in a comment.

Why do I receive the error in console?

Thank you

---

### Edit

As asked, I insert the code of *App.vue* and *HelloWorld.vue*:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
@Component({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

HelloWorld.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>
      For a guide and recipes on how to configure / customize this project,<br>
      check out the
      <a href="https://cli.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">vue-cli documentation</a>.
    </p>
    <h3>Installed CLI Plugins</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-babel" target="_blank" rel="noopener">babel</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-typescript" target="_blank" rel="noopener">typescript</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Essential Links</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Core Docs</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://forum.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://chat.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Community Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/vuejs" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://news.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">News</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Ecosystem</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://router.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vuex.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#vue-devtools" target="_blank" rel="noopener">vue-devtools</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vue-loader.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank" rel="noopener">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

main.ts:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Sorry to be a bit blunt on this, but you said you wanted to keep the question as clear as possible but you start off explaining something completely different and then don't post anything from `App.vue` which is what the error message references. Could you explain why you thought `App.vue` would not be relevant?

Comment: @DFM it's not relevant because it's taken by `@vue/cli` default application, so it's something that who used the cli already seen and I supposed it wasn't worthing insert it in the question. But since you thought it's not clear, I'm going to put it